# Show TODO tasks only for pending changes in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, todo

The Task List in Visual Studio 2010 will show all the TODO comments in a solution, but is there some way to filter it to only show TODOs for files with pending changes or for files that are open?  In other words, I don't want to see everyone else's TODOs, only the TODOs in my changeset.  If it isn't built in, is there a plug-in that you like that can do that?

Answer (score 2):

**Task List** window lists all comments what contains **TODO** keyword. Also there are two default keywords; **HACK** and **UNDONE**. VS doesn't allow to change or delete **TODO** keyword but allows add new keywords. If you add a special keyword (like **RoToDo**) into **Token List** (it located in **Tools/Options/Enviroment/Task List**) and use this keyword in your comments like "//***RoToDo*** comment here", Task List window will show these comments too. Finally; you can use Task List window's sorting property for gathering your special comments.

> ***RoToDo** comment here1*
>   
> ***RoToDo*** comment here2
>   
> ***RoToDo*** comment here3
>   
> ***RoToDo*** comment here4
>   
> ***todo :*** comment here1
>   
> ***todo :*** comment here2
>   
> ***todo :*** comment here3